# python subprocess is overwriting file used for stdout - I need it to append to the file (windows)

Tags: python, windows, file, subprocess, stdout

I want to append the `STDOUT` of `subprocess.call()` to an existing file. My code below overwrites the file -

```
log_file = open(log_file_path, 'r+')
cmd = r'echo "some info for the log file"'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=log_file, stderr=STDOUT)
log_file.close()
```

I'm looking for the equivalent of `>>` in `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. It's driving me crazy trying to find it..

UPDATE:

Following the answers so far I've updated my code to

```
import subprocess

log_file = open('test_log_file.log', 'a+')
cmd = r'echo "some info for the log file\n"'
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=log_file, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
log_file.close()
```

I'm running this code from the command line in windows -

```
C:\users\aidan>test_subprocess.py
```

This adds the text to the log file. When I run the script again, nothing new is added. It still seems to be overwriting the file..

Comment: This is a deeper issue on Windows and append mode, see https://bugs.python.org/issue45237 for workarounds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the 'a' append mode instead:

```
log_file = open(log_file_path, 'a+')
```

If you still see previous content overwritten, perhaps Windows needs you to explicitly seek to the end of the file; open as 'r+' or 'w' and seek to the end of the file:

```
import os

log_file = open(log_file_path, 'r+')
log_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - that makes sense, but somehow it still fails (I've updated my question with a complete script).

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a seek-to-end alternative to opening the file for appending.

Answer (score 4):

Modify how you open log_file_path. You are opening the file for reading and writing 'r+'. Use the 'a' append mode instead of 'r+':

```
log_file = open(log_file_path, 'a+')
```