# Python subprocess not honoring append mode for stdout on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

On Windows, if you pass an existing file object in append mode to a subprocess,
the subprocess does **not** really append to the file:

1. A file object with `Hello World` content is passed to the subprocess
2. The content is erased
3. The subprocess writes to the file
4. The expected output does not contain `Hello World`

Demo:

```
import subprocess, time, pathlib, sys
print(f'Caller {sys.platform=} {sys.version=}')

pathlib.Path('sub.py').write_text("""import sys, time
time.sleep(1)
print(f'Callee {sys.stdout.buffer.mode=}')""")

file = pathlib.Path('dummy.txt')
file.write_text('Hello World')
popen = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'sub.py'], stdout=file.open(mode='a'))
file.write_text('')
time.sleep(2)
print(file.read_text())
```

I get the expected output

```
Caller sys.platform='linux' sys.version='3.8.6'
Callee sys.stdout.buffer.mode='wb'
```

and the unexpected bad output

```
Caller sys.platform='win32' sys.version='3.8.6'
NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULCallee sys.stdout.buffer.mode='wb'
```

Is this a Python bug, and how can I make this work on Windows?

Note that the expected output is given on Windows if the file is opened in the subprocess via `sys.stdout = open('dummy.txt', 'a')`. So it is definitely a subprocess thing.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722752) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389158) on SO hinting at the problem without a solution for me.

Comment: Just submitted https://bugs.python.org/issue45237

Comment: Thanks to Eryk Sun, the question now has [two workarounds](https://bugs.python.org/issue45237)